# code to insert values into db2 table in python

Tags: python, db2

I want to insert variable values into db2 table using Python code

```
  id = input("table id:   ")
  tabname = input("Enter Table name:   ")
  descr = input("Enter description :   ")
  inser_sql = "INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(id, tabname, descr)
        stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, inser_sql)
        ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

this code gives me error:

```
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, inser_sql)
```

> Exception: statement must be a string or unicode

Comment: @AchinthaIhalage, [`id` isn't a keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=keywords#keywords), it's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id). It's not a good idea to shadow `id`, but there's nothing stopping you from doing it.

Comment: am not using id as variable in my code, it is by mistake here, variable names are fine.

Comment: The second argument to ibm_db.prepare must be a strng.

Comment: @Rashmi , your code is incorrect in at least two ways. First is that the ibm_db.prepare needs the second argument to be a string. Second is that you must run ibm_db.bind_param for each of the parameter-markers shown in the prepared SQL, indicating their data-type, before you run the ibm_db.execute.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table is defined like this:

```
"create table myschema.mytable(id int, tabname varchar(10), description varchar(10))"
```

I understand your intention is to insert a specific row into it with a prepared statement and parameter markers. 
Skipping the input part:

```
In [14]: id = 1
In [15]: tabname = 'TAB'
In [16]: descr = 'my desc'
```

you just need to prepare the statement first, bind the parameters later and then execute:

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO  myschema.mytable VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
prep_stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, insert_sql)
ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 1, id)
ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 2, tabname)
ibm_db.bind_param(prep_stmt, 3, descr)
ibm_db.execute(prep_stmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer will depend on the specific DB2 library you're using, but the variable holding your query should just be a plain string.

You will probably need to pass parameters to it when you *execute* the statement:

```
inser_sql = "INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, inser_sql)
ibm_db.execute(stmt, (id, tabname, descr))
#                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```